# Were there any folding wing biplanes?

Tags: military, aviation-history, aircraft-carrier, biplane, folding-wings

Given that several nations had operational carriers by 1920 and biplanes were still in military service, were there any folding wing biplanes?

[image]

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_for_aircraft_carrier_service#/media/File:USS_Langley_(CV-1)_and_USS_Somers_(DD-301)_underway_off_San_Diego,_in_1928_(NH_81279).jpg): United States first purpose built aircraft carrier, USS Langley (1920), note no biplanes have wings folded.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Blackburn Ripon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackburn_Ripon) -- a British carrier-based torpedo bomber -- is such example (first flight 1926):

[image]
Source: [aviadejavu.ru](http://aviadejavu.ru/Site/Crafts/Craft26110.htm) via *Flight*

[image]
Source: [Imperial War Museums](https://www.iwm.org.uk/collections/item/object/205212400) -- seen here landing on [HMS *Furious*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Furious_(47))

---

Earliest mentions I found -- not necessarily carrier-based, *and* not necessarily real(?):

[image]
Source: [*Flight*](https://www.flightglobal.com/pdfarchive/view/1911/1911%20-%200645.html) -- 1911

[image]
Source: [*Flight*](https://www.flightglobal.com/pdfarchive/view/1915/1915%20-%200705.html) -- folding wings on the *aerial-saw* concept from 1915 (click image to view)

Answer (score 3):

Fairey Swordfish, operated off Royal Navy carriers in WW2.  Supermarine Walrus, a single engine pusher flying boat carried on cruisers.  Similar vintage.